# Pagination for custom query on single.php

Tags: wp-query, pagination, single

I'm building a site and the basic structure on most pages is as follows:

```
<!-- content query -->
<!-- recent posts preview query (paginated) -->
<!-- related posts preview query (paginated) -->
```

The paginated content is loading on the same page using jQuery, so just that specific section updates when the user navigates to the next page or a section.

Most of my pages are literally pages with custom templates on which I run custom queries (WP_query) for each thing.  This works really well on the custom pages, but I am trying to implement it similarly on single.php.  The structure I want on single.php is:

```
<!-- post content -->
<!-- recent posts preview query (paginated) -->
<!-- related posts preview query (paginated) -->
```

However, my code that works perfectly fine on custom pages has broken pagination on single.php.  Researching this, it seems it may be conflicting with the fact that posts themselves can be paginated.  I've not been able to find much more info than that.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve my goal here?
Is there any workaround, in any capacity that would make it happen?

Thank you very much for any insight you might be able to offer!

Comment: Did you try [searching the site for questions related to custom loop pagination](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination)?

Comment: Of course! The trouble is, it's not an issue with paginating custom loops (as I'm successfully paginating these same loops in other places on the site).  Rather, it's a question of whether something besides the post (in this case, additional loops) can be paginated in single.php specifically.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Out of curiosity: does your pagination work on static Pages that are *themselves* paginated, or only on single-page static Pages?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean exactly. All my pages are comprised of multiple paginated WP_queries, so I think they are all single-page static Pages? All content is paginated within the Page itself. How would pages that are themselves paginated work, so I am sure I'm understanding? I can test it if I understand properly. Sorry for my lack of understanding! Thanks for replying again! :)

Comment: Well, for anyone else looking to solve a similar problem, I found this post, and it led me in the right direction: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-on-singlephp-causing-301-redirect> . I added the snippet of code at the bottom to my functions.php, and my code is working now. I don't know enough about it to know what it does, but it seems to fix the problem! Thanks, Chip, for your help!

Comment: could you post that as an **answer**, with the code you used to fix (and then *accept* that answer)? Glad you solved the issue; I'm not sure how my questions helped, but if they did - great! :)

Comment: Sorry about that! This is only my second question, so I'm still learning the protocol.  I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow, so I will make sure and do it then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for anyone else looking to solve a similar problem, I found this post, and it led me in the right direction: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-on-singlephp-causing-301-redirect?replies=9.

I added this snippet of code to my functions.php, and I can paginate in custom queries without issue on single.php now. I don't know enough about it to know what it does, but it seems to fix the problem!

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
    if (is_singular('pov_channel')) $redirect_url = false;
return $redirect_url;
}
```